# Facebook SDK get permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a Facebook login to work on my website. I'm running the following code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '1340103676056632',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.8'
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
          };

          (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            function myFacebookLogin() {
              FB.login(function(){ 

              FB.api('/me','GET',{"fields":"email,birthday,gender,hometown,location"}, {scope:'user_location,email,user_birthday'},
              function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              }
            );
            })
            }
```

I'm getting the following response in the console.log:

> Object
>   id
>   :
>   "1223808051065376"
>   name
>   :
>   "Kevin Tinnemans"

while according to the Graph API explorer I should get the following output.

```
{
  "email": "email@hotmail.nl",
  "birthday": "01/01/1900",
  "gender": "male",
  "hometown": {
    "id": "123456789",
    "name": "Narnia"
  },
  "location": {
    "id": "123456789",
    "name": "secret, secret, Netherlands"
  },
  "id": "123456789"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.login(function() { 
    FB.api('/me','GET',{"fields":"email,birthday,gender,hometown,location"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
}, {scope:'user_location,email,user_birthday'});
```

Make sure to use the object with the scope parameter as second parameter of `FB.login`, to get asked for the additional permissions.